# Scraping an API returns what looks like encrypted data

Tags: python, web-scraping, encryption, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape match stats from the following page:

```
https://www.atptour.com/en/scores/stats-centre/archive/2022/407/MS002
```

Rather than build a complex Selenium scraper to read the JavaScript enabled bits I thought I'd have a go at finding an API to scrape using `requests`.

From looking through the Network tab I thought I'd start with the following:

```
requests.get("https://itp-atp-sls.infosys-platforms.com/prod/api/match-beats/status/year/2022/eventId/407/matchId/MS002")
```

This does return a result but it's gobbledygook (to me at least).

I'm assuming it's some kind of encrypted response. Is there a way of decrypting it as the browser does?

---

**Edit:**

Here's the response:

```
{"lastModified":1663265556422,"response":"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"}
```

Comment: Separate from the core of your question, but why would you *necessarily* need to use Selenium to accomplish this (other than mocking the API calls)? Seems [someone on GitHub](https://github.com/serve-and-volley/atp-world-tour-tennis-data) has successfully scraped the style of links you cite using `requests` and BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Seen that repo but it was written before Infosys started providing match stats via Javascript and their API. If you check out the Issues tab you'll see the author recognises this and has assigned themselves a task to look at it.

Comment: Ah, interesting - thanks for pointing that out! The info returned from Infosys' systems does appear to be *encoded* in Base64 but decodes to what appears to be some binary format - there must be something in the JavaScript on the page that decodes it for presentation, but the JavaScript itself has been minified/obfuscated to make reverse engineering that mechanism incredibly difficult. I would recommend editing your post to include a response from that endpoint in the body of your question to lower the barrier for others who may be able to assist further.

Answer (score 5):

Better late than never!

**In short**: they are just using the lastModified field from the query as a key to encrypt the data with AES128.

The piece of code that decodes the data on their front-end:

```js
var Ou = function(t) {
        var e = function(t) {
            var e = (new Date).getTimezoneOffset()
              , n = new Date(t.getTime() + 60 * e * 1e3).getDate()
              , r = parseInt((n < 10 ? "0" + n : n).toString().split("").reverse().join(""))
              , i = t.getFullYear()
              , a = parseInt(i.toString().split("").reverse().join(""))
              , o = parseInt(t.getTime().toString(), 16).toString(36) + ((i + a) * (n + r)).toString(24)
              , s = o.length;
            if (s < 14)
                for (var c = 0; c < 14 - s; c++)
                    o += "0";
            else
                s > 14 && (o = o.substr(0, 14));
            return "#" + o + "$"
        }(new Date(t.lastModified))
          , n = Jo.a.enc.Utf8.parse(e)
          , r = Jo.a.enc.Utf8.parse(e.toUpperCase())
          , i = Jo.a.AES.decrypt(t.response, n, {
            iv: r,
            mode: Jo.a.mode.CBC,
            padding: Jo.a.pad.Pkcs7
        });
        return JSON.parse(i.toString(Jo.a.enc.Utf8))
    };
```

Refactored it a bit and after installing `npm i crypto-js` if using nodejs ,
you get the decoded data:

```js
// const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js"); // If Nodejs

const data = {"lastModified":1663265556422,"response":"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"};

function decode(data) {
  var e = formatDate(new Date(data.lastModified))
    , n = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(e)
    , r = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(e.toUpperCase())
    , i = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data.response, n, {
      iv: r,
      mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
      padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });
  return JSON.parse(i.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8))
};

function formatDate(t) {
  var e = (new Date).getTimezoneOffset(), n = new Date(t.getTime() + 60 * e * 1e3).getDate(), r = parseInt((n < 10 ? "0" + n : n).toString().split("").reverse().join("")), i = t.getFullYear(), a = parseInt(i.toString().split("").reverse().join("")), o = parseInt(t.getTime().toString(), 16).toString(36) + ((i + a) * (n + r)).toString(24), s = o.length;
  if (s < 14)
    for (var c = 0; c < 14 - s; c++)
      o += "0";


  else
    s > 14 && (o = o.substr(0, 14));
  return "#" + o + "$";
}

console.log(decode(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

I hope it helped :)

Comment: Thanks a million for looking at this :) The challenge I've got is that I use Python for everything and I'll like very much to keep doing this! Is there a Python equivalent to the above?

Comment: How did you find the piece of code that decodes the data on their front-end?

Comment: I just had a look, this file seems to be the main source with everything in it.
https://itp-atp-sls.infosys-platforms.com/itp/prod/atp/match-centre/main.js
Look for "lastModified", you should find the code then.